# validate strings in an excel in vb.net

Tags: excel, vb.net

I have a question, in vb.net, how can i validate that 2 values are the same in an excel in vb.net

for example i have defined 3 list

```
Public NSPS As New List(Of String)

Public CONTAINER As New List(Of String)

Public CONTAINER2 As New List(Of String)
```

I have 2 excel files where CONTAINER and CONTAINER2 are id's

So i need to create a third excel file that filters only the id's that repeat themselves in the 2 excel

meaning if i have an id: CARU9891569 in the 2 files, only then it transfers to the generated excel

and the 2 excel's have some extra information, for example: excel 1 has the variables: DELIVERY, CONTAINER, VOLUME.
the second excel has the variables: NSPS, NPOS, PACKAGES, CONTAINER2

SO the generated excel needs to have all of the variables: DELIVERY, CONTAINER, VOLUME, NSPS, NPOS, PACKAGES. using CONTAINER as the filter

to just fill information in a new excel i use this code

i use a function like this to extract the information from the excel files

```
 Function extraer_valores_planilla(ByRef ruta As String) As Boolean
            ExcelPackage.LicenseContext = LicenseContext.NonCommercial
            Try
                Dim stream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(ruta)
                Dim package = New OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage(stream)
                '//  Libro
                Dim Workbook = package.Workbook
                '//  Hojas
                Dim hojas = Workbook.Worksheets
    
                ' While (Workbook.Worksheets.Count >= aux)
                Dim hojaUsuarios = Workbook.Worksheets(Workbook.Worksheets.Item(0).ToString)
                Dim indice As Integer = 2
    
                While (indice < 5000)
                    'Numero entrega'
                    If (IsNothing(hojaUsuarios.Cells("A" & indice).Value) = False) Then
                        NSPS.Add(hojaUsuarios.Cells("A" & indice).Value)
                    End If
                      indice += 1
            End While
            indice += 1
        Catch EX As Exception
            MsgBox(EX.ToString)
            Return False
        End Try
        Return True
```

and then i fill the third excel like this

```
Private Sub Button5_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click

        ExcelPackage.LicenseContext = LicenseContext.NonCommercial
        Dim path As String = seleccionardirectorio("Excel|.xlsx")
        If (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(path) = False) Then

            Dim excel = New ExcelPackage(New FileInfo(path))
            excel.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Hoja1")
            Dim aux As Integer = 1
            Dim Workbook = excel.Workbook
            Dim hojas = Workbook.Worksheets
            Dim dict As New Dictionary(Of String, String)
            Dim hoja1 = Workbook.Worksheets("Hoja1")
            'DAMOS NOMBRE A LAS COLUMNAS 
            INICIALIZAR_PLANILLA(hoja1)
               While (aux <= CONTAINER.Count)

                hoja1.Cells("C" & aux + 1).Value = ENTREGA.Item(aux - 1)
                aux += 1

            End While
```

this is the same for all variables i just resume for you guys and this works just fine.

should i use 2 cicles to filter the excel, maybe a for each, sorry i am new to programing and i am stuck in this part

any ideas would be helpfull

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

yes, use 2 **for each** loops.

```
for each item in list
    for each otheritem in list2
        if item = otheritem then
            ' These items match
        end if
    next
next
```

Replace the dummy variables with yours